# Firebase iOS Push Notifications not working on first install

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I first install and open the app and accept the notifications permission alert from Apple, I get this log from Firebase:

> 5.16.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023004] Could not update attributes of the key pair to be accessible after first unlock. update
>   status: -25300

After that, if I close or send the app to the background I don't receive any notifications. If I open the app a second time, then notifications start working normally.

This is my current setup:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    setupPushNotificationsHandling(application)
    return true
}

private func setupPushNotificationsHandling(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, _) in
        guard granted else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

            FirebaseApp.configure()
            InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, _) in
                // Receive notifications from the "all" topic
                Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "all")
            }
        }
    }
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("response \(response)")
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: Firebase.configure(), put this in your app delegate. then you can get the instanceId after registerForRemoteNotification happened.

Comment: @karthik - Thanks, but I already have `Firebase.configure()` on my app delegate, is right before I call `InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID`.

Comment: i could see you are calling after registerForRemoteNotification. put the configure before registering.

Comment: Placed the `configure` call before registering; same problem.

Comment: I am having this same issue - any solution?

Comment: @cheesydoritosandkale I posted my solution below, that didn't work for you?

Comment: Whenever I try to use it, I always get this error `Static member 'instanceID' cannot be used on instance of type 'InstanceID'`

Comment: Having a similar problem - simple notif registration. Doesn't allow me to handle notification taps (am getting them though) on first install + registration. From the second time launching the app, everything works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I called `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` just after `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self`. then problem solved. but dont know the reason why it worked !

Comment: and also  this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/74328358/9440709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

1. Before attempting to subscribe to a notifications topic, I wait until the delegate method `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` is called.
2. I retry until the call `InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID` returns a valid device token.

Complete setup:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    setupPushNotificationsHandling(application)
    return true
}

private func setupPushNotificationsHandling(_ application: UIApplication) {
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (_, _) in }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Receive notifications from the "all" topic
    subscribeToNotificationsTopic(topic: "all")
}

func subscribeToNotificationsTopic(topic: String) {
    // Retry until the notifications subscription is successful
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        var subscribed = false
        while !subscribed {
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

            InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
                if let result = result {
                    // Device token can be used to send notifications exclusively to this device
                    print("Device token \(result.token)")

                    // Subscribe
                    Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: topic)

                    // Notify semaphore
                    subscribed = true
                    semaphore.signal()
                }
            }

            // Set a 3 seconds timeout
            let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(3)
            _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: dispatchTime)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem and solved using @AlejandroCotilla's answer. Please note that with Firebase ver 8.10.0, "InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID .." has been rename to "Installations.installations().installationID ..".