# Firebase iOS Push notification not receiving on first app launch

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I follow all the steps given in below link.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#analytics-enabled
Firebase version : Firebase 7.3.0

The notification is working if I quit fist launch. Then there is no problem. Only having issue for the first time app launch.

Comment: Are you using Topics or token?

Comment: I am having the same issue. How you have solved this @Rajesh Maurya?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: I have met the same problem and solved using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489861/firebase-ios-push-notifications-not-working-on-first-install/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while googling a lot I found a lot and this works for me by downgrading the firebase SDK version:

pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 6.33.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 6.33.0'

I hope this could help you. And it seems the Firebase team has not yet fixed this issue in their new milestone

Comment: @Rajesh Maurya Please accept the answer if it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling `method swizzling` worked for me.

`method swizzling`: giving APNS token to firebase by ourself instead of letting firebase to take it automatically.

**

### To disable method swizzling:

( 1 ). Add `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` the app’s ***Info.plist*** file and setting it to **NO** (boolean value).

[image]

---

( 2 ). Implement the `application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)` method of `UIApplicationDelegate` to retrieve the APNs token, and then set Messaging's `apnsToken` property:

```swift
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
  Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

**