# Push notification is not receiving when the app is installed for first time

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

When I installed the app for first time the push notification is not receiving, if I kill the app and open again the push notifications is working fine.
When I console the code and trigger the push notification manually through FCM , I found that the notification data is not receiving on the onMessage function and on getInitialNotification() the result shows as undefined.

Please check the below code for getting push notifications and also the packages and versions which I have used.

Packages :
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.5.0",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
"react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",

Code :

```
componentWillUnmount() {
if (Platform.OS === "ios" && this.messageListener1 && this.messageListener2) {
this.messageListener1();
this.messageListener2();
}
}
async requestUserPermission() {
const { navigate } = { ...this.props }
const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
const enabled =
authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
if (enabled) {
this.messageListener1 = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
PushNotification.localNotification({
/* Android Only Properties */
id: remoteMessage.data.id, // (optional) Valid unique 32 bit integer specified as string. default: Autogenerated Unique ID
autoCancel: true, // (optional) default: true
vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true
vibration: 300, // vibration length in milliseconds, ignored if vibrate=false, default: 1000
group: remoteMessage.data,
userInfo: {
data: remoteMessage.data,
},
title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
message: remoteMessage.notification.body,
});
});
messaging()
.getInitialNotification()
.then(async remoteMessage => {
if (remoteMessage) {
if (await GlobalStorage.handleInitialNotification(remoteMessage)) {
navigate(remoteMessage);
PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: remoteMessage.data.id });
}
}
});
this.messageListener2 = messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
GlobalStorage.handleInitialNotification(remoteMessage)
navigate(remoteMessage);
PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: remoteMessage.data.id });
});
```

Note : There is no issues in getting the FCM token.

Comment: I have a same issues. Did you solve it? But i am swift

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74328358/9440709 this worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is only facing mainly on android device and here is solution I used to solve the issue

```
 const { navigate,
            } = { ...this.props }
            PushNotification.configure({
                onRegister: function (token) {
                   
                },
                onNotification: function (notification) {
                    const clicked = notification.userInteraction ? notification.userInteraction : "";
                    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
                    if (clicked) {
                        navigate(notification);s
                        PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: notification.id });
                    } else if (!notification.foreground) {
                        navigate(notification);
                        PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: notification.id });
                    }
                    else {
                        PushNotification.localNotification({
                            /* Android Only Properties */
                            channelId: "app_name", // (required)
                            channelName: "app_name", // (required)
                            id: notification.id, // (optional) Valid unique 32 bit integer specified as string. default: Autogenerated Unique ID
                            // autoCancel: true, // (optional) default: true
                            vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true
                            vibration: 300, // vibration length in milliseconds, ignored if vibrate=false, default: 1000
                            group: notification.data, // (optional) add group to message
                            priority: "high", // (optional) set notification priority, default: high
                            visibility: "private", // (optional) set notification visibility, default: private
                            importance: "high",
                            userInfo: {
                                id: notification.id,
                                name: "name",
                                title: notification.title,
                                message: notification.message,
                                data: notification.data

                            },
                            title: notification.title,
                            message: notification.message,
                        });
                    }
                    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
                },
                senderID: "",
                permissions: {
                    alert: true,
                    badge: true,
                    sound: true
                },
                popInitialNotification: true,
                requestPermissions: true
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

- I faced the same problem.
- I tried all the packages and the result is the same in all of them.
- Here's the situation:

*Everything is fine with the Notification integration.

*When you install the application for the first time, there is no notification.

*When you open the application for the first time and kill it in the background and open it again and throw it into the background, everything works fine. You start receiving notifications.

It's really interesting. Has anyone experienced this and know what exactly is causing the issue?